# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i have a XML File i want to insert data from that XML file to the Database

if tried with the following code but its not storing data in datatase

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'corporatenews/$zname' INTO TABLE `corporatenews` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES STARTING BY '<row>' TERMINATED BY '</row>' (`ByLine`,`StoryId`,`PublishDate`,`Author`,`Category`,`SubCategory`,`TitleLine`,`SubTitleLine`,`StoryMain`,`Flag`)";
```

$zname is the variable that stores the xml file name

i tried to catch error by mysql_error but nothing showed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be overcomplicating things by trying to shove the file directly into MySQL.  For a simple solution you may be able to read the entire XML file into memory w/ **file_get_contents**, then just insert it into MySQL from PHP.

EDIT: Per OP request for clarification.

OK, well there are a bunch of ways to parse an XML file in PHP, the easiest way IMO is [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  Basically, you want to read in the file, and then iterate over it creating a bunch of **INSERT** statements.  It could be quicker to batch the insert statements, but forget about that for now.

The code would be something like this (this code assumes the MySQL connection is setup properly):

```
// iterate over XML elements
$oXml = new SimpleXMLElement('path/to/file.xml', 0, true);
foreach($oXml as $oElement) {
  // build main part of query
  $sSql = 'INSERT INTO (`ByLine`,`StoryId`,`PublishDate`,`Author`,`Category`,`SubCategory`,`TitleLine`,`SubTitleLine`,`StoryMain`,`Flag`) VALUES (';

  $sSql .= $oXml['ByLine'] . ',';
  $sSql .= $oXml['StoryId'] . ',';

 // ..

}
```

Basically you use SimpleXML to extract the data from the XML attributes / child nodes, then you  build up a string you can pass to **mysql_query**.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that am a starter

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), they show you how to access an XML document with SimpleXMLElement and get to attributes of various nodes.  All you have to do is apply that to your document, then once you have the fields in variables from a node, throw those into an SQL statement (in a string) and lastly issue the INSERT for each node in the document that needs to correlate to a new database entry.